# Below are my c# codes i get system error message

Tags: c#

[image]

This is my codes
using visual studio 2015
But when I am trying add role value i get the system error message "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format"

```
        CDMSSEntities db;

        private void frmUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new CDMSSEntities();
            roleBindingSource.DataSource = db.Roles.ToList();
            userBindingSource.DataSource = db.Users.ToList();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User user = new User();
            userBindingSource.Add(user);
            userBindingSource.MoveLast();
            db.Users.Add(user);
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete record?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                db.Users.Remove(userBindingSource.Current as User);
                userBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
            }
        }

        private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                userBindingSource.EndEdit();
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                dataGridView.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("data saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're putting an **"Admin"** which is a **String** into a field that accepts only **Int-32** values. Can you show us your database design?

You probably want to put 1,2,3 or whatever ID your "Admin" role has, instead of actually typing "Admin".